# Import swift class into objective c storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storyboard, interface-builder

Im trying to integrate implement the project  https://github.com/ariok/BWWalkthrough into my objective c project.

I have an objc bridging header that Xcode automatically made for me

I translated the ViewController.swift code as such

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Walkthrough" bundle:nil];
BWWalkthroughViewController *walkthrough = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"walk"];
BWWalkthroughPageViewController *page_zero = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"walk0"];
BWWalkthroughPageViewController *page_one = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"walk1"];
BWWalkthroughPageViewController *page_two = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"walk2"];
BWWalkthroughPageViewController *page_three = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"walk3"];

walkthrough.delegate = self;
[walkthrough addViewController:page_zero];
[walkthrough addViewController:page_one];
[walkthrough addViewController:page_two];
[walkthrough addViewController:page_three];

[self presentViewController:walkthrough animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and I import the swift classes like so:

## import "SkipTheLine-Swift.h"

My bridging header file's name is "SkipTheLine-Bridging-Header.h"

now, when I run the code, I get this

2015-04-25 16:47:46.740 SkipTheLine[1631:215786] Unknown class BWWalkthroughViewController in Interface Builder file.
2015-04-25 16:47:46.754 SkipTheLine[1631:215786] -[UIViewController setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12651cf90
2015-04-25 16:47:46.755 SkipTheLine[1631:215786] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12651cf90'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1838aa530 0x19482c0e4 0x1838b15f4 0x1838ae3ac 0x1837b2c4c 0x10009c494 0x1880eca14 0x1880d5d08 0x1880ec3b0 0x1880ec03c 0x1880e5590 0x1880b8e60 0x18835846c 0x1880b73d0 0x183862d34 0x183861fd8 0x183860088 0x18378d1f4 0x18cbb76fc 0x18811e10c 0x10009e174 0x194eaaa08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Any ideas as to how I can use the swift code in interface builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out!

You just need to edit the MODULE in the interface builder to the name of the project!!

Comment: It worked for me to set the module name to BWWalkthrough when using CocoaPods to integrate BWWalkthrough.